Not receiving webhooks from Google Calendar events API
I have an app that subscribes to Google Calendar using events#watch API.
Here is the thing: I can pick any calendar I have access to watch except one (the main Personal calendar). For all other calendars, I'm receiving webhooks just fine, except one and I have no idea where to look for. I wonder if it rings a bell for anyone?
I do however receive webhooks where the HTTP_X_GOOG_RESOURCE_ID does match a channel that exists but all other info like HTTP_X_GOOG_CHANNEL_TOKEN and HTTP_X_GOOG_CHANNEL_ID don't exist in my database.
I'm using Ruby, google-apis-calendar_v3 (0.44.0) for the integration
